# Split a string in between elements of interest

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string (mathematical equation):

```
Wt=mgt
```

This is what I would like to split them by: `['wt', 'm', 'g', 't']`

I would like the result `['Wt', '=', 'm', 'g', t']`

I am not sure how to do this.

### Clarification:

This should be applicable to all equations inputted. My goal is to have the user input an equation and an array, and split the string into a another array using the initial array they gave me:

```
split('Wt=mg', ['Wt', 'm', 'g']) // => ['Wt', '=', 'm', 'g']
split('maa=tna', ['ma', 'a', 't', 'n']) // => ['ma', 'a', '=', 't', 'n', 'a']
split('Fnet=ma', ['Fnet', 'm', 'a']) // => ['Fnet', '=', 'm', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a master on `RegEx` so maybe there is a more elegant way to do this, but try this, it seems to work ok with your values:

```js
console.log(splitStr('Wt=mg', ['Wt', 'm', 'g'])) // => ['Wt', '=', 'm', 'g']
console.log(splitStr('maa=tna', ['ma', 'a', 't', 'n'])) // => ['ma', 'a', '=', 't', 'n', 'a']
console.log(splitStr('Fnet=ma', ['Fnet', 'm', 'a'])) // => ['Fnet', '=', 'm', 'a']

function splitStr(string, array){
    const matches = `(${array.join("|")}|=)`
    return string.split(new RegExp(matches)).filter(f => f != '')
}
```

The trick here is to create a regex with stucture `(value1|valueN|=)` with all values in the array and then split by these values.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for answering. However, my goal was to use this on many equations, so if I have this one: `ma+maa = tmaa`, and I want to split it by these variables: ma, a, and t, it doesn't work because not all of my equations follow the pattern I described above.

Comment: Oh I see, so, what mathematical operations can exists. Is always the same structure `value = value` where value can contains `+`, `-`, `/` or `*`?

Comment: I am not making these equations, the user will. Yes, the equations is always `a = b`.

Comment: And how you can difference when separe characters and when do not do that?. For example `Wt` keep together but `mgt` is `m, g, t`.

Comment: You can assume that all variables not mentioned in the array are being multiplied. For example, if the user gives me an array of `['Wt', 'n', 't']` and an equation of `WT = nt`, because 'nt' is not a single item in the array but two items, but `Wt` is only one item in the array, it should split `nt` but leave `wt` alone. The expected output for this example is: `['Wt', '=', 'n', 't']

Comment: So the user gives you the inital string and an array with values?

Comment: Yes. That is what happens.

Comment: I added more examples. Thanks

Comment: Edited answer, hope it works ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case you can use something like this.

```js
let str = "Wt=mgt"
let strArr = str.split("=")
let res = [strArr[0], ...strArr[1].split("")];
console.log(res)
```

For the second result you can use the above method and just insert the "=" in between.

```js
let str = "Wt=mgt"
let strArr = str.split("=")
let res = [strArr[0],"=", ...strArr[1].split("")];
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entriely sure what your requirement here but you can do something like this:

```java
List<String> final = new ArrayList<String>();
String toAdd = "";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
    int c = (int) s.charAt(i);        
    if((c > 32 && c < 47) || (c > 58 && c < 64) || (c > 91 && c < 96) || (c > 123 && c < 126)){
        final.push(toAdd);
        final.push(s.charAt(i));
    }
    else{
        toAdd += s.charAt(i);
    }
}
```